# Java EE 7/Glassfish - data from rest resource loads with Curl but, not from a HTML/Knockout.js client

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I've used a [Netbeans tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIEBo2AUDkA) to create a rest service based on entity classes. The rest resource is then consumed by a backbone.js client.

The problem I'm having is that there is a line in jquery that is causing the html/backbone.js page to not load the rest data. I can get the XML data when I enter the resource address, `http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1/webresources/com.blah.project1.customer`, in my browser or when I Curl it.

Is there a there a  JAX-RS configuration file that I am missing that would allow a web page to load the data?

From Chrome's inspector:
[image]

From Jquery.min.js, the offending line is 3815: `f.send(a.hasContent && a.data || null )`

```
n.ajaxTransport(function(a) {
    var b;
    return k.cors || Fc && !a.crossDomain ? {
        send: function(c, d) {
            var e, f = a.xhr(), g = ++Cc;
            if (f.open(a.type, a.url, a.async, a.username, a.password),
            a.xhrFields)
                for (e in a.xhrFields)
                    f[e] = a.xhrFields[e];
            a.mimeType && f.overrideMimeType && f.overrideMimeType(a.mimeType),
            a.crossDomain || c["X-Requested-With"] || (c["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest");
            for (e in c)
                f.setRequestHeader(e, c[e]);
            b = function(a) {
                return function() {
                    b && (delete Dc[g],
                    b = f.onload = f.onerror = null ,
                    "abort" === a ? f.abort() : "error" === a ? d(f.status, f.statusText) : d(Ec[f.status] || f.status, f.statusText, "string" == typeof f.responseText ? {
                        text: f.responseText
                    } : void 0, f.getAllResponseHeaders()))
                }
            }
            ,
            f.onload = b(),
            f.onerror = b("error"),
            b = Dc[g] = b("abort");
            try {
                f.send(a.hasContent && a.data || null )
            } catch (h) {
                if (b)
                    throw h
            }
        },
        abort: function() {
            b && b()
        }
    } : void 0
}),
```

The Glassfish server log shows this whenever the page is requested. I know this was a bug in glassfish last year but, since chrome is showing a jquery error, too - I don't think the bug is not being caused by Glassfish.

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.mycompany.mavenproject1.service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet
com.mycompany.mavenproject1.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.validateAndTransformIfNeeded(JAXBMarshaller.java:587)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:481)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:949)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:683)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:424)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:414)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:312)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Edit:

Since this page also shows an error alert when it first loads and, the error alert states: `Unable to fulfil the request`, I know the load failure happens becuase of the backbone.js script for some reason:

```
var app = {
// Create this closure to contain the cached modules
module: function () {
    // Internal module cache.
    var modules = {};

    // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
    // existing module.
    return function (name) {
        // If this module has already been created, return it.
        if (modules[name]) {
            return modules[name];
        }

        // Create a module and save it under this name
        return modules[name] = {Views: {}};
    };
}()
};

(function (models) {

// Model for Customer entity
models.Customer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1/webresources/com.mycompany.mavenproject1.customer/",
    idAttribute: 'customerId',
    defaults: {
        city: "",
        phone: "",
        name: "",
        addressline2: "",
        creditLimit: "",
        addressline1: "",
        state: "",
        fax: "",
        email: ""
    },
    toViewJson: function () {
        var result = this.toJSON(); // displayName property is used to render item in the list
        result.displayName = this.get('name');
        return result;
    },
    isNew: function () {
        // default isNew() method imlementation is
        // based on the 'id' initialization which
        // sometimes is required to be initialized.
        // So isNew() is rediefined here
        return this.notSynced;
    },
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        var errorHandler = {
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // TODO: put your error handling code here
                // If you use the JS client from the different domain
                // (f.e. locally) then Cross-origin resource sharing 
                // headers has to be set on the REST server side.
                // Otherwise the JS client has to be copied into the
                // some (f.e. the same) Web project on the same domain
                alert('Unable to fulfil the request');
            }
        };

        if (method === 'create') {
            options.url = 'http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1/webresources/com.mycompany.mavenproject1.customer/';
        }
        var result = Backbone.sync(method, model, _.extend(options, errorHandler));
        return result;
    }


});


// Collection class for Customer entities
models.CustomerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: models.Customer,
    url: "http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1/webresources/com.mycompany.mavenproject1.customer/",
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        var errorHandler = {
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // TODO: put your error handling code here
                // If you use the JS client from the different domain
                // (f.e. locally) then Cross-origin resource sharing 
                // headers has to be set on the REST server side.
                // Otherwise the JS client has to be copied into the
                // some (f.e. the same) Web project on the same domain
                alert('Unable to fulfil the request');
            }
        };

        var result = Backbone.sync(method, model, _.extend(options, errorHandler));
        return result;
    }
});
})(app.module("models"));

(function (views) {

views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        var self = this;
        this.model.bind("add", function (modelName) {
            var row = new views.ListItemView({
                model: modelName,
                templateName: self.options.templateName
            }).render().el;
            $(self.el).append($(row));
            $(self.el).parent().trigger('addRows', [$(row)]);
        });
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        var self = this;
        _.each(this.model.models, function (modelName) {
            $(this.el).append(new views.ListItemView({
                model: modelName,
                templateName: self.options.templateName
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

views.ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },
    template: function (json) {
        /*
         *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
         *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
         *  using jQuery 
         */
        return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    close: function () {
        var table = $(this.el).parent().parent();
        table.trigger('disable.pager');
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).remove();
        table.trigger('enable.pager');
    }

});

views.ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    template: function (json) {
        /*
         *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
         *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
         *  using jQuery 
         */
        return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
    },
    /*
     *  Classes "save"  and "delete" are used on the HTML controls to listen events.
     *  So it is supposed that HTML has controls with these classes.
     */
    events: {
        "change input": "change",
        "click .save": "save",
        "click .delete": "drop"
    },
    change: function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        console.log('changing ' + target.id + ' from: ' + target.defaultValue + ' to: ' + target.value);
    },
    save: function () {
        // TODO : put save code here
        var hash = this.options.getHashObject();
        this.model.set(hash);
        if (this.model.isNew() && this.collection) {
            var self = this;
            this.collection.create(this.model, {
                success: function () {
                    // see isNew() method implementation in the model
                    self.model.notSynced = false;
                    self.options.navigate(self.model.id);
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.model.save();
            this.model.el.parent().parent().trigger("update");
        }
        return false;
    },
    drop: function () {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function () {
                /*
                 *  TODO : put your code here
                 *  f.e. alert("Model is successfully deleted");
                 */
                window.history.back();
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).empty();
    }
});

// This view is used to create new model element
views.CreateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.render();
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    template: function (json) {
        /*
         *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
         *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
         *  using jQuery 
         */
        return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
    },
    /*
     *  Class "new" is used on the control to listen events.
     *  So it is supposed that HTML has a control with "new" class.
     */
    events: {
        "click .new": "create"
    },
    create: function (event) {
        this.options.navigate();
        return false;
    }
});

})(app.module("views"));


$(function () {
var models = app.module("models");
var views = app.module("views");

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'list',
        'new': 'create'
        ,
        ':id': 'details'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('#create').html(new views.CreateView({
            // tpl-create is template identifier for 'create' block
            templateName: '#tpl-create',
            navigate: function () {
                self.navigate('new', true);
            }
        }).render().el);
    },
    list: function () {
        this.collection = new models.CustomerCollection();
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                self.listView = new views.ListView({
                    model: self.collection,
                    // tpl-customer-list-itemis template identifier for item
                    templateName: '#tpl-customer-list-item'
                });
                $('#datatable').html(self.listView.render().el).append(_.template($('#thead').html())());
                if (self.requestedId) {
                    self.details(self.requestedId);
                }
                var pagerOptions = {
                    // target the pager markup 
                    container: $('.pager'),
                    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; possiblevariables: {page}, {totalPages},{startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
                    output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
                    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
                    page: 0,
                    // Number of visible rows - default is 10
                    size: 10
                };
                $('#datatable').tablesorter({widthFixed: true,
                    widgets: ['zebra']}).
                        tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
            }
        });
    },
    details: function (id) {
        if (this.collection) {
            this.customer = this.collection.get(id);
            if (this.view) {
                this.view.close();
            }
            var self = this;
            this.view = new views.ModelView({
                model: this.customer,
                // tpl-customer-details is template identifier for chosen model element
                templateName: '#tpl-customer-details',
                getHashObject: function () {
                    return self.getData();
                }
            });
            $('#details').html(this.view.render().el);
        } else {
            this.requestedId = id;
            this.list();
        }
    },
    create: function () {
        if (this.view) {
            this.view.close();
        }
        var self = this;
        var dataModel = new models.Customer();
        // see isNew() method implementation in the model
        dataModel.notSynced = true;
        this.view = new views.ModelView({
            model: dataModel,
            collection: this.collection,
            // tpl-customer-details is a template identifier for chosen model element
            templateName: '#tpl-customer-details',
            navigate: function (id) {
                self.navigate(id, false);
            },
            getHashObject: function () {
                return self.getData();
            }
        });
        $('#details').html(this.view.render().el);
    },
    getData: function () {
        return {
            customerId: $('#customerId').val(),
            city: $('#city').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            name: $('#name').val(),
            addressline2: $('#addressline2').val(),
            creditLimit: $('#creditLimit').val(),
            addressline1: $('#addressline1').val(),
            state: $('#state').val(),
            fax: $('#fax').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        };
    }
});
new AppRouter();


Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - I was working on this project using Netbeans to auto-generate the code. First, it created entity classes from a database, then rest classes to access the entity classes, and finally it auto-generated a rest client using Knockout.js.

However, Netbeans did not add org.json, com.sun.jersey, and com.sun.jersey to the pom.xml file. I added the above dependencies and now, I can get json responses as expected.